# Is anyone building a Lightning-like network on Ethereum?

Tags: lightning

Is anyone building a Lightning-like network on Ethereum, offering cheap microtransactions and secure 0-confs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heiko Hees has presented such project at the DEVCON1 conference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h791zjvf3uQ

It is called Raiden. According to Heiko, it is implementable with the current capabilities of Ethereum network, unlike Lightning or Duplex Micropayment Channels, which both require some changes in the Bitcoin (even if simply fixing transaction malleability issues).

Here is the Raiden's github:
https://github.com/heikoheiko/raiden

Answer (score 3):

hot off the press: http://etherapis.io Micropayment platform for generic API calls built on ethereum.

Also see SWAP https://github.com/ethersphere/swarm/wiki/Swap which is a specification for generic micropayment scheme suited for pairwise accounting between peers. Its go implementation using ethereum is used for accounting in the swarm decentralised content distribution and storage platform.

Both by the ethereum go team

Comment: Thanks for your first answer.  As a guideline answers (and questions) should be able to stand alone (links may die).  Including the most relevant parts from the links will improve this answer.

Comment: Links are quite fine if they directly answer the question. The question was "is anyone building ...". The answer is "Yes, here are some examples" as opposed to just "Yes", which is an answer to the question. However if we look at the question we can derive that the person is looking for examples other than just confirmation of the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

The Go Ethereum Swarm guys are working on SWAP, a micro payment channels for the SWARM protocol.

Peter and myself have been working on Etherapis (see Viktor's comment), a Gohergala (a golang code competition).

Another example is my [whisper-payment-channel](https://github.com/obscuren/whisper-payment-channel). While the other answers either require a separate executable or client this example requires no modification to [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) and requires no additional software other than an Ethereum node supporting Whisper.